# authorized_keys Environment Variables Not Setting Environment Variables

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, ssh-keys

I have created the file ~/.ssh/environment in there I put:

```
LEVEL=0
```

When I run a script over ssh to get the environment variable level it returns 0 like it should.

In the authorized_keys file I have several keys and am trying to change the value on a few so when I run a script on the other side it can modify how it process information. I am adding the following before the normal key:

```
command="/path/to/script" environment="LEVEL=1"
```

If I don't have the environment segment the script is executed fine, but if I have the environment part set then the script won't run.

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. Am I even approaching this correctly?

essentially I have 4 different keys and in some cases I want people to have a level 1 or 2 with the default of 0, but I want to set who has the level and have it only set while they are logged in to execute their command.

I think I am barely understanding how it is supposed to work so my understanding could be completely wrong on how this should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need commas between the options. But you don't actually need the `environment` option, see [toppledwagon's answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/256098/authorized-keys-environment-variables-not-setting-environment-variables/256108#256108).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
command="export LEVEL=1; /path/to/script"
```

Answer (score 7):

There option **PermitUserEnvironment** in config file */etc/ssh/sshd_config* has default value to **no**

So to enable processing file `~/.ssh/environment` or/and `environment=` options in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` set above variable in **yes**

Comment: This may not answer the actual question (?) but it answered what I was trying to figure out, so have some points on me :)

Comment: this is exactly what i m looking for !!

Answer (score 5):

First guess is that your syntax is slightly off.

I've never personally used the "environment" argument before, but from having to write custom authorized_keys entries before, I believe that optional arguments at the beginning of an authorized_keys entry require commas between each argument, not spaces.

Try:

```
command="path/to/script",environment="LEVEL=1" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArestofkeyhere comment_stuff
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped it to work most of the way. I am going to play with it a little bit more I think I might still have something off. For the meantime though I am going with toppledwagon's solution. Thanks.

Comment: For this to work, on the server side the admin must add `PermitUserEnvironment yes` to the `sshd_config`. Setting the environment variable as part of the forced command such as in [the other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/256108/98062) works without changes to the server configuration.